# Why I did not get two None statements here since both x and y are void functions?

Tags: python, function

```
def x():
    def y():
        print('hi there this is y function')
    y()
    print('this is function x')

print(x())
```

output :

```
hi there this is y function
this is function x
None
```

I was expecting None to be printed after the function x calls y since y is a void function

expected output:

```
 hi there this is y function
 None
 this is function x
 None
```

Comment: Please provide link to place in python documentation where definition of *void function* is given

Comment: You aren't printing the return value from calling `y()`.

Comment: print() result None at the end only since  its first call x(), inside that y() will be called, then after everything print() itself is called which will print None, as empty print () type is None, you can check it through `print(type (print()))`, and the called function is given more preference.

Comment: How many `print` statements do you have, and which do you expect to print what…?

Answer (score 0):

Printing the return value of a function is done by your runtime environment, not by Python itself.  So only the function that returns to the environment will print a value.

Many times the value `None` results in no printing at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your expected output, you need to print y().

```
def x():
    def y():
        print('hi there this is y function')
    print(y())
    print('this is function x')

print(x())
```

Answer (score -1):

You will not return anything, because you don't use the "return" statement. If you don't use return, you will have no return (not even None)

Furthermore you don't have to declare a function as "void".

Comment: `None` is returned implicitly when `return` is missing…